Confusion regarding method of successive bisection used in Apostol's Calculus Volume 1
In his book, quite a few of his proofs used the method of successive bisection as a way to argue by contradiction that certain theorems must be true. However, there are certain places in the proof I found incomplete (or it seemed circular to me), and I would really appreciate if someone can explain it to me. During his proof using the method of successive bisection, he assumed that the theorem is false in both intervals (left and right), and if the theorem is false in both intervals, then he chooses the left interval and continues to bisect. But I got this question. His proof showed that the theorem being false in the left subinterval leads to a contradiction, but he never really showed that the right subinterval leads to a contradiction in the case that it is also false (So how can he really conclude that the interval must really be true?). It just seems circular to me. I have also thought that maybe you could just apply the same principle to the right subinterval, but again the right subinterval can also contain right subintervals where the theorem is false).
Here is an example of the proof of boundless theorem (i.e if a function f is continuous on a closed interval [a,b]. Then f is bounded on [a,b])
"Suppose that $f$ is not bounded on the interval [$a,b$].
Let $c$ be the mid point of [$a,b$] . $f$ will be unbounded in at least one of the two intervals [$a,c$] and [$c,b$] . We choose the interval on which it is unbounded (in case it is unbounded on both, we choose the left interval). We call this interval as [$a_1,b_1$].
This process of bisection is carried out indefinitely so that the interval [$a_{n+1},b_{n+1}$] denotes that half of [$a_n,b_n$] in which $f$ is unbounded. In case it is unbounded on both halves, the left half is selected.
The length of the $n$th interval is $(b-a)/2^n$.
Let $A$ denote the set of leftmost endpoints $a,a_1,a_2,a_3...$ so obtained. Let $\alpha$ denote the supremum of $A$. Then $\alpha$ lies in $[a,b]$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$ , there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that
$$ 
|f(x)| < 1 + |f(\alpha)|
$$
in the interval $(\alpha -\delta,\alpha + \delta)$
(In case $\alpha = a$ , the interval should be $[a,a + \delta)$.
In case $\alpha = b$ , the interval should be $(b - \delta,b]$.)
However , the interval [$a_n,b_n$] lies inside the interval $(\alpha -\delta,\alpha + \delta)$, provided  $(b-a)/2^n < \delta$.
Therefore, f is bounded in $(b-a)/2^n$ , which is a contradiction , hence completing the proof.
"
I don't really understand how picking the left interval is sufficient for the proof. Consider two subintervals [$a_{n+1},c_{n+1}$], [$c_{n+1},b_{n+1}$] of an arbitrary interval [$a_n,b_n$], where $c_{n+1}$ is the midpoint of [$a_n,b_n$]. If the entire interval [$a_n,b_n$] is unbounded (i.e every subinterval of it is also unbounded), and assume that the proof is sufficient for proving that the left interval [$a_{n+1},c_{n+1}$] must be bounded. But he still left out showing that the right subinterval [$c_{n+1},b_{n+1}$] must be bounded to show that the subinterval [$a_n,b_n$] is cannot be unbounded. This contradicts that any subinterval [$a_n,b_n$] can be shown to be true by this method whenever it is completely unbounded (including the left subinterval [$a_{n+1},c_{n+1}$]). I just feel like he should also prove that the theorem on the right interval being false also leads to a contradiction.
Thank you in advance.
